# How to send formatted string to socket using a small buffer?

Tags: c, sockets, printf

I am trying to write some xml data to a socket in C. I can print the xml string to the screen using:

```
printf("<tag1>%d</tag1>"
       "<tag2>%s</tag2>"
       "<tag3>%s</tag3>"
       "<tag4>%d</tag4>",
       int1,
       str2,
       str3,
       int4);
```

Instead of printing to stdout, I try to `snprintf` that string to a buffer (`char[]`), then write the buffer's contents to a socket. Unfortunately, I imagine that here the buffer could be full during the write of either `str2` or `str3` and perhaps not even big enough to contain either string.

Using `snprintf` it is easy to check whether I was able to write all the data to the buffer, but not easy to continue where I left off after sending buffer contents to a socket.

Basically: Is there functionality that would let me send, say, 64 bytes at a time of `"%d%s%s%d"` to a socket, should the formatted string be longer than 64 bytes?

If this functionality does not exist I'm interested in what workarounds you'd suggest (If it helps, you can assume the `%s` fields are populated by an evil robot that tries to overflow your buffer, regardless of size).

Comment: Use `snprintf`. If the buffer isn't large enough, enlarge the buffer and call `snprintf` again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using `fprintf` with a socket descriptor?

Something like:

```
int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
FILE *fd = fdopen(sockfd, "w")
fprintf(fd, "<tag1>%d</tag1>"
   "<tag2>%s</tag2>"
   "<tag3>%s</tag3>"
   "<tag4>%d</tag4>",
   int1,
   str2,
   str3,
   int4);
fflush(fd);
```

Comment: Thanks! Is the `fflush` still necessary if all my `fprintf`s are newline-terminated?

Comment: Not sure but they don't heart anybody. Better explicit than implicit :)

Comment: Yes, you need to `fflush` with `fdopen` (or `setvbuf` once just after `fdopen`).

Comment: @PauloBu what about using `dprintf` directly? Would it work?

Answer (score 4):

On Linux at least with [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) you could use [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) (which gives a `malloc`-ed string) or [dprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dprintf.3.html) (which prints into a file descriptor).

You could also (and more portably) [fdopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fdopen.3.html) the socket file descriptor then [fprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3.html) **and [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html)** it. You could configure buffering with [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html).

[fileno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fileno.3.html) is quite useful too...

BTW, [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) is returning the number of *needed* bytes. So you might code

```
char tinybuf[100];
char* buf = tinybuf;
int nbytes= snprintf(tinybuf, sizeof(tinybuf), 
                     "<tag at='%d'>%s</tag>", num, string);
if (nbytes >= sizeof(tinybuf)) { // rarely happens
    char *buf = malloc(nbytes+1);
    if (!buf) { perror("malloc"); abort(); };
    snprintf(buf, nbytes+1, 
             "<tag at='%d'>%s</tag>", num, string);
};
int off=0;
while (nbytes>0) {
   int nbw=write(sock, buf+off, nbytes); 
   if (nbw>0) { off += nbw; nbytes -= nbw; };
   else if (nbw<0 && errno != EINTR) { perror("write"); abort(); };
};
if (buf != tinybuf) free(buf);
```

This would avoid `malloc` and `free` in the common case that `tinybuf` fits...