# How to properly use snprintf to format info into a buffer and sscanf to get that info back

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I want to store different types of variables into a buffer to a char array so that I can send it and when the server receives it I want to take that formatted buffer and get the variables back.

I have found 0 examples of how to make this work, everyone makes it look as such a simple task that they do not provide the output, so I tried it for myself.

I've made a dumb program where I store and extract without even sending, to get used to formats and avoid all the problems I've read about buffer overflow and whatnot.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int op = 1; //1 porque es un alta
    int pid = getpid();
    printf("pid %d\n", pid);
    char * tema = argv[1];
    printf("Tema %s\n", tema);

    int longitud = strlen(tema) + sizeof(int) * 2 + 1;
    /
    printf("longitud %d\n", longitud);

    char mensaje[longitud];
    char * ptr = mensaje;

    snprintf(ptr, longitud, "%d %d %s", op, pid, tema);
    printf("mensaje %s\n", mensaje);

    int opRecibido = 0;
    int pidRecibido = 0;
    char * temaRecibido;
    sscanf(mensaje, "%d %d %s", & opRecibido, & pidRecibido, temaRecibido);

    printf("temaRecibido %s\n", temaRecibido);
    printf("pidRecibido %d\n", pidRecibido);
    printf("opRecibido %d\n", opRecibido);

}
```

Of course I've tried several iterations of this. I can't get it right. temaRecibido either writes null, or segfault, or nothing works, etc.

Again, I want this as a way to serialize my data before sending it from a TCP client to a server, but I can't even make this work, without sending it.

The part that does not work is the sscanf. I've read about everything I've found googling it specially

[Since we have snprintf, why we don't have a snscanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368712/since-we-have-snprintf-why-we-dont-have-a-snscanf?lq=1)

and

[How to send formatted string to socket using a small buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981736/how-to-send-formatted-string-to-socket-using-a-small-buffer)

But there's something I'm clearly missing

Edit: And since I'm at it, and I see so many comments and blogs telling me not to use sscanf, please what would be the proper way of solving this stance? Because every single example I see works with 1 or 2 char* and it's simply not helping me

Answer (score 0):

Allright so I've done this getting ideas from somewhere and I believe it works:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int op=1;//1 porque es un alta
int pid=getpid();
printf("pid %d\n", pid);
char * tema=argv[1];
printf("Tema %s\n", tema);

int longitud=strlen(tema)+sizeof(int)*2+2;
printf("longitud %d\n", longitud);

char mensaje[longitud];//crea array tamaño deseado: tamanio del nombre del tema recibido mas los dos int a enviar
char *ptr=mensaje;

int nbytes = longitud;
char *my_string;
my_string = (char *) malloc (strlen(tema) + 1);

snprintf(mensaje, longitud,"%d %d %s", op, pid,tema);
printf("mensaje %s\n", mensaje);
printf("my_string %s\n", my_string);


int opRecibido=0;
int pidRecibido=0;
sscanf(mensaje, "%d %d %s", &opRecibido, &pidRecibido, my_string);

printf("pidRecibido %d\n", pidRecibido);
printf("opRecibido %d\n", opRecibido);
printf("myString %s\n", my_string);

}
```

So basically doing malloc of the proper size so I can then store info. Something like that

Answer (score -1):

This `int longitud=strlen(tema)+sizeof(int)*2+1;/`
should have been

```
int longitud=strlen(tema)+sizeof(int)*2+1 + 2;// +2 for additional space induced between the types.
```

The additional two bytes is from here

`snprintf(ptr, longitud,"%d<space>%d<space>%s", op, pid,tema);`

Comment: not saying that's not the case (I wouldn't have ever guessed that'd be a problem so thanks), but I still get segmentation fault when trying to use sscanf.

Comment: Now that it somewhat works, I get the three variable printed, it works with +1 and +2. And no idea why. If I don't add anything, I miss the last character, which makes sense. Just wanted to add that